# How to split pandas dataframe into multiple dataframes based on unique string value without aggregating

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with multiple country codes in a column (US, CA, MX, AU...) and want to split this one df into multiple ones based on these country code values, but without aggregating it.

I've tried a for loop but was only able to get one df and it was aggregated with groupby().

I gave up trying to figure it out so I split them based on str.match and wrote one line for each country code. Is there a nice for loop that could achieve the same as below code? If it would write a csv file for each new df that would be fantastic.

```py
us = df[df['country_code'].str.match("US")]
mx = df[df['country_code'].str.match("MX")]
ca = df[df['country_code'].str.match("CA")]
au = df[df['country_code'].str.match("AU")]
```

.
.
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can write a for loop which takes each code and uses `query` to get the correct part of the data. Then we write it to csv with `to_csv` also using `f-string`:

```
codes = ['US', 'MX', 'CA', 'AU']

for code in codes:
    temp = df.query(f'country_code.str.match("{code}")')
    temp.to_csv(f'df_{code}.csv')
```

*note: `f_string` only work if `Python >= 3.5`*

---

To keep the dataframes:

```
codes = ['US', 'MX', 'CA', 'AU']

dfs=[]
for code in codes:
    temp = df.query(f'country_code.str.match("{code}")')
    dfs.append(temp)
    temp.to_csv(f'df_{code}.csv')
```

Then you can acces them with the index, for example: `print(dfs[0])` or `print(dfs[1])`.

Comment: That was so cool! Thank you so much.

Out of curiosity, if I still wanted to work on these data files. How could I create a new df for each of the country codes?

Comment: Thank you!! This is really helpful. Have an amazing day!