# Save multiple dataframes into the environment in Python

Tags: python, pandas, f-string

I have a similar problem with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57452403/how-to-split-pandas-dataframe-into-multiple-dataframes-based-on-unique-string-va) but the original question was to make multiple csv output. In my case, I am wondering if there's a way to make the multiple dataframe output into environment through a loop so I can carry on some data analysis.

```
us = df[df['country_code'].str.match("US")]
mx = df[df['country_code'].str.match("MX")]
ca = df[df['country_code'].str.match("CA")]
au = df[df['country_code'].str.match("AU")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same code as the link posted, but save the different dfs into a dictionary:

```
codes = ['US', 'MX', 'CA', 'AU']
result_dict = {}
for code in codes:
    temp = df.query(f'country_code.str.match("{code}")')
    result_dict[code] = temp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create `for` and check like below and create `dict` for match:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'country_code': ['US','MX', 'CA', 'AU']})
codes = ['US', 'MX', 'CA', 'AU']
out = {code : df[df['country_code'].str.match(code)] for code in codes}
```

Output:

```
>>> out["US"]
     country_code
0    US

>>> type(out["US"])
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame


>>> out["CA"]
     country_code
2    CA
```